# How does the Soda Popper's Hype ability work?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-scout

I've recently unlocked the soda popper for the scout class. I love the weapon and use it as my go-to scattergun. In the weapon description it mentions that when hype has been built up, pressing alt+fire will activate a special ability. However, when I press alt+fire with a full hype bar, the weapon fires and nothing else happens. If I right click, the weapon glows purple with no other effect (except I think it might be giving me critical hits from behind; I'm not sure though). Why is nothing happening when I press alt+fire and what is happening when I right click?

Comment: If you did not know about the Soda Popper's ability, why did you prefer the weapon to the Force of Nature?

Comment: @AustinMohr I only have the soda popper and the default scattergun at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, when the weapon description says 'alt fire', they mean alternate fire (right-click by default), not alt and fire at the same time.  Many weapons have alternate fire methods, including the pyro's airblast for his flamethrower, and the medic's ubercharge when his uber meter is full.

The weapon discription for the soda popper is somewhat incomplete, due to the unusual nature and history of the Soda Popper.

**What it does now** is provides 5 additional mid-air jumps (on top of the extra jump Scouts already have, plus any additional jumps granted by other items) while this ability is active.  Simply right-click when the meter is full, and you will be granted these additional mid-air jumps.

**In this past** this weapon would automatically activate, and provide mini-crits.  This is likely why the weapon today has an inaccurate description.

http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Soda_Popper

Answer (score -1):

it gives you mini-crits for a couple of seconds I'm pretty sure thought the wiki says it gives you mid-air jumps I'm VERY sure it give crits again or at least mini-crits